# Split datetime column into separate date and time columns

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, time

I am trying to extract a Date and a Time from a Timestamp:

```
DateTime   
31/12/2015 22:45
```

to be:

```
   Date   |  Time   |
31/12/2015|  22:45  |
```

however when I use:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime']).dt.date
```

I Get :

```
2015-12-31
```

Similarly with Time i get:

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime']).dt.time
```

gives

```
23:45:00
```

but if I try to format it I get an error:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(f['DateTime'], format='%d/%m/%Y').dt.date

ValueError: unconverted data remains:  00:00
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try strftime

```
df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'])
df['Date'] = df['DateTime'].dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
df['Time'] = df['DateTime'].dt.strftime('%H:%M')


    DateTime            Date        Time
0   2015-12-31 22:45:00 31/12/2015  22:45
```

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1**
Since you don't really need to operate on the *dates* per se, just split your column on space:

```
df = df.DateTime.str.split(expand=True)   
df.columns = ['Date', 'Time']
```

```
df
         Date   Time
0  31/12/2015  22:45
```

---

**Option 2**
Alternatively, just drop the format specifier completely:

```
v = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'], errors='coerce')

df['Time'] = v.dt.time
df['Date'] = v.dt.floor('D')
```

```
df
       Time       Date
0  22:45:00 2015-12-31
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `DateTime` column is already a datetime type, you shouldn't need to call `pd.to_datetime` on it.

Are you looking for a string (`"12:34"`) or a timestamp (the concept of `12:34` in the afternoon)?  If you're looking for the former, there are answers here that cover that.  If you're looking for the latter, you can use the `.dt.time` and `.dt.date` accessors.

```
>>> pd.__version__
u'0.20.2'
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'DateTime':pd.date_range(start='2018-01-01', end='2018-01-10')})
>>> df['date'] = df.DateTime.dt.date
>>> df['time'] = df.DateTime.dt.time
>>> df
    DateTime        date      time
0 2018-01-01  2018-01-01  00:00:00
1 2018-01-02  2018-01-02  00:00:00
2 2018-01-03  2018-01-03  00:00:00
3 2018-01-04  2018-01-04  00:00:00
4 2018-01-05  2018-01-05  00:00:00
5 2018-01-06  2018-01-06  00:00:00
6 2018-01-07  2018-01-07  00:00:00
7 2018-01-08  2018-01-08  00:00:00
8 2018-01-09  2018-01-09  00:00:00
9 2018-01-10  2018-01-10  00:00:00
```